# Why doesn't my iPod Classic show all the songs it holds?

Tags: ipod

I recently bought a new iPod Classic 120GB, mainly to use on my Numark iDJ2 but also for general use.

I have it set so that all my iTunes songs are automatically pulled over to it and when I look at its contents on iTunes all my songs are there. However, if I unplug it and then search through it manually, some artists don't appear. (I haven't yet found a pattern.)

The only reason I mention my iDJ2 is that I have Numark's 'Librarian' software installed on my iPod so that the iDJ2 can categorize and play all of my songs. I don't see how it should be responsible for this problem though.

Any help much appreciated and let me know if you need any more info.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that some albums are tagged as "**Compilation**"? In this case the artists in these albums are not shown in the "*Artists*" submenu... Uncheck the "**Compilation**" check-box (or something like that - I don't use iTunes!) in the *Information tab* and they magically appear in the list.

PS. When you select an artist that "has" a proper album, the songs in the **Compilation albums** are also shown.