# iPod doesnt show songs, iTunes and Explorer does

Tags: data-synchronization, ipod, itunes

I have a black iPod Classic 160GB. I use iTunes on Windows 7 to sync songs. I can see the songs that are synced with the iPod, iniTunes. However, after ejecting, the iPod shows 0 songs. Going to settings show the decreased free space. Opening up My Computer, and I can see the songs in the `ipod_control\Music` folder. I have also set the songs to not be a part of a compilation, as suggested in this [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/10896/why-doesnt-my-ipod-classic-show-all-the-songs-it-holds). However, I have been unsuccessful in getting the iPod to show the songs. I am tired after fiddling with it since 2 days now. What gives?

Comment: Are you adding songs manually or automatically? (i.e. what is the setting set to in iTunes?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, remove all songs from the device (from within iTunes) and then try re-adding them. If that fails to have any effect, remove all songs, unplug the iPod, re-plug, and add a few back. (Don't bother checking for songs in Explorer; that's not going to help.)

If that doesn't work, back up any data that has made it to your iPod and restore the firmware in iTunes. Then try to add a single song and see if that works. (Add a playlist with one song, then try dragging one over manually, if you prefer that setting.)

Comment on what worked or didn't: if nothing works, I'll come up with more things to try.

Comment: I tried manual and auto sync at first, still did not work. Then I did a restore, and synced songs, manually, and afterwards, automatically. I can see the songs in the iPod now. Restoring the iPod from iTunes did the trick.